# Cut Python DataFrame row to multiple parts based on a keyword

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python DataFrame containing rows having '\n' included between values in multiple column. I want to split the signle row having values along with '\n' to multiple rows.

Below is the example of the dataframe.

```
        A                       B
ABC\n\nXYZ\n\n\nPQR     123\n\n456\n754
```

I want to create the output as below

```
        A                       B
       ABC                     123 
       XYZ                     456
       PQR                     754
```

One way I can think off is to create separate List for both the columns, split it by '\n' and then join both of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let use `str.split` and `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda r: r.str.split(r'[\\n]+',expand=True)
                    .dropna(1).stack())
  .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  ABC  123
1  XYZ  456
2  PQR  754
```